# Due to Certain parameters page not loading

Tags: php, request, firebug

It's pleasure to be here; hoping a good support from all.

I am developing this application using personal FrameWork `(CITS: construesol.com/our-solutions/cits-framework.html)`

Facing the following issue, and not sure if this is due to some server or issue in my framework.

This Works: `wrosc.commbuss.com/index.php`

This gives Page not found error:

```
wrosc.commbuss.com/index.php?login__ga=GA1.2.1438238513.1446927241&
login_ck_login_id_20=1&
login_ck_login_language_20=en_us&
login_default_horde_view=auto&
login_PHPSESSID=evnvh60rcd8j37b64ajbb02vi7&
login_feacc482788c1ab9a7c03bcd5b19c90e=CookieEnabledClient
```

These are the additional paramaters passed from my machine; may be due to some tools I am using with my browser; like FireBug

```
&login__ga=GA1.2.1438238513.1446927241&
login_ck_login_id_20=1&
login_ck_login_language_20=en_us&
login_default_horde_view=auto&
login_PHPSESSID=evnvh60rcd8j37b64ajbb02vi7&
login_feacc482788c1ab9a7c03bcd5b19c90e=CookieEnabledClient
```

I am running a loop for `$_REQUEST` to check if some parameters are passed to redirect user to proper module (Parameters received: This is the feature of the framework).

The problem is only with this machine (and all developer) and not on "Non-Developer" machines; As we think this is due to some tools we are using with browser (e.g. FireBug)

NOTE: **** "login_" in front of each parameter is performed by the framework

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the bug: Issue was with Framework, handled using urlencode

***But still those parameters are passed.